# Libgdx getProperties().get("value") give me strange response

Tags: java, libgdx, tmx

I have a strange response with `getProperties().get("value")`.

You can see below my `tmx file` and values provided by my program.

```
 <objectgroup name="objects">   <object id="1" name="player" type="player" x="256" y="3072" width="1290" height="1290">    <properties>
    <property name="name" value="Ahhhh"/>
    <property name="nom" value="Bhhhh"/>
    <property name="velocity" value="1.0"/>    </properties>   </object>  </objectgroup>
```

Source code

```
    MapObject mapPlayer = currentMap.getLayers().get("objects").getObjects().get("player");
MapObjects mapObject = currentMap.getLayers().get("objects").getObjects();
for (Iterator<String> iter = mapPlayer.getProperties().getKeys(); iter.hasNext(); )
{
    System.out.println("#############"+iter.next());
}
System.out.println("**************** player name :  " + mapPlayer.getProperties().get("name", String.class));
RectangleMapObject rect = (RectangleMapObject) mapObject.get("player");
float x = (float) rect.getRectangle().x;
float y = (float) rect.getRectangle().y;
float width = rect.getRectangle().width;
float height = rect.getRectangle().height;

System.out.println("**************** player coordinates X :  " +x);
System.out.println("**************** player coordinates Y:  "+y);
System.out.println("**************** player coordinates width :  " +width);
System.out.println("**************** player coordinates height:  "+height);
System.out.println("**************** player coordinates X :  " +mapPlayer.getProperties().get("x", Integer.class));
System.out.println("**************** player coordinates Y:  "+mapPlayer.getProperties().get("y", Integer.class));
System.out.println("**************** player velocity :  "+mapPlayer.getProperties().get("velocity", Integer.class));
```

> #######width
>   
>   #######name
>   
>   #######nom
>   
>   #######id
>   
>   #######velocity
>   
>   #######height
>   
>   #######x
>   
>   #######y
>   
>   #######type
>
> **************** player name :  Ahhhh
>   **************** player coordinates X :  256.0
>   **************** player coordinates Y:  3318.0
>   **************** player coordinates width :  1290.0
>   **************** player coordinates height:  1290.0
>   **************** player coordinates X :  256.0
>   **************** player coordinates Y:  3318.0
>   **************** player velocity :  1.0

Why Y hasn't show the correct value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because libgdx has the Y axis the other way around (pointing upwards instead of downwards like in Tiled) and is trying to be helpful by automatically converting the Y coordinates into its own coordinate space when loading the map.

Comment: Exactly, this is the reason. I didn't understand because it's easy to understand if width & height are a tile multiple (256 in my case), but if it's another value it can be more complex. Obviously Y is inverted. Thanks.